# VTK, Python: How can I connect vtkpoints and visualise them as a surface?

Tags: python, vtk

I currently have a code that visualises vtkpoints that I take from an OBJ file:

```
poly = vtkPolyData()
poly.SetPoints(points) //points from obj file
sphere = vtkSphereSource()
sphere.SetRadius(.7)
sphere.SetThetaResolution(4)
sphere.SetPhiResolution(4)
glyph = vtkGlyph3D()
glyph.SetSourceConnection(sphere.GetOutputPort())
glyph.SetInputData(poly)
mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(glyph.GetOutputPort())
self.actor = vtkActor()
self.actor.SetMapper(mapper)
self.ren.AddActor(self.actor)
self.vtkWidget.Render()
```

so then each of my points on my OBJ file is visualised as a sphere. However, I was wondering if there is a way to just connect these points and visualise them as a surface? I've tried vtksurfacereconstruction filter and delaunay, but that produces horrific results, nothing even close to what I need.

Comment: Dear @Spencer, could you post some input data and expected output to illustrate what problems you are facing. It will increase the probability to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done using a Delaunay filter.

https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDelaunay3D.html
https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDelaunay2D.html

And it works quite well for most cases.

You will need to share a dataset to get other kind of infos.